# Angular-UI: Popover doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui

Here is an example that I've created, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
<button popover-placement="bottom" popover-template="'calendar.html'" popover-trigger="click"><h1>Hello Plunker!</h1></button>

<script id="calendar.html" type="text/ng-template">
  <datepicker ng-model="date" show-weeks="false"></datepicker>
</script>
```

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/eOnbjTd7rTOPbrZYSdkv?p=preview)

I've also tried without using apostrophes in the `popover-template` attribute, but no avail.

Can someone tell me where I'm wrong with the implementation? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few issues:

You were loading ui-bootstrap before angular, so it failed (I put ui-bootstrap after angular.js):

```
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.5/angular.js" data-semver="1.5.5" data-require="angularjs@1.5.5"></script>
<script data-require="ui-bootstrap@*" data-semver="1.3.2" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/gh-pages/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.3.2.js"></script>
```

The datepicker directive was not being called, because it requires "uib-" (note uib-datepicker):

```
<button popover-placement="bottom" uib-popover-template="'calendar.html'" popover-trigger="click"><h1>Hello Plunker!</h1></button>
```

The datepicker directive was also not being called, because it requires "uib-" (note uib-datepicker):

```
<script id="calendar.html" type="text/ng-template">
  <uib-datepicker ng-model="date" show-weeks="false"></datepicker>
</script>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/wXJp2aMBOci2heugHAeQ?p=preview